# Как сделать реализацию на весь товар на складе 1с ут 11

Tags: 1с

В управлении торговлей 11 есть товар 3700 наименований на складе - его надо весь продать на другую фирму задним числом. Тоесть товар который числится 15 числа продать весь 16ым числом.

Как заполнить проще всего? Строки из пересчёта товаров не копируются в реализацию. через ввод на основании тоже не получается.

При заполнении из внешнего файла не получается у программы сопоставить номенклатуру.